# Error Resolving 'sockjs-client' and 'stompjs' in React and Spring Data Rest Project

Tags: javascript, reactjs, websocket, sockjs, stompjs

I am following this React and Spring Data Rest tutorial and am currently at Part 4: https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/react-and-spring-data-rest

I have completed all the steps for Part 4. However, when attempting to run the project I am getting errors. Running `./mvnw clean install` I get the following errors:

```
[INFO] ERROR in ./src/main/js/websocket-listener.js
[INFO] Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'sockjs-client' in '.../src/main/js'
[INFO]  @ ./src/main/js/websocket-listener.js 3:13-37
[INFO]  @ ./src/main/js/app.js
[INFO] 
[INFO] ERROR in ./src/main/js/websocket-listener.js
[INFO] Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'stompjs' in '.../src/main/js'
[INFO]  @ ./src/main/js/websocket-listener.js 4:0-18
[INFO]  @ ./src/main/js/app.js
```

The websocket-listener.js file I am using is as follows:

```
// websocket-listener.js
'use strict';

const SockJS = require('sockjs-client');
require('stompjs');

function register(registrations) {
  const socket = SockJS('/payroll');
  const stompClient = Stomp.over(socket);
  stompClient.connect({}, function(frame) {
    registrations.forEach(function (registration) {
      stompClient.subscribe(registration.route, registration.callback);
    });
  });
}

module.exports.register = register;
```

I have attempted to add the `resolve: { alias: { 'stompjs': ... } }` as suggested. However, the `stompjs` error still appears. The current webpack.config.js file I am using is:

```
// webpack.config.js
var path = require('path');

module.exports = {
    entry: './src/main/js/app.js',
    // change devtool from 'sourcemap' to 'eval-source-map' for webpack5 compliance
    devtool: 'eval-source-map',
    cache: true,
    mode: 'development',
    resolve: {
      alias: {
        'stompjs': path.resolve(__dirname, 'node_modules/stompjs/lib/stomp.js'),
      },
    },
    output: {
        path: __dirname,
        filename: './src/main/resources/static/built/bundle.js'
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: path.join(__dirname, '.'),
                exclude: /(node_modules)/,
                use: [{
                    loader: 'babel-loader',
                    options: {
                        presets: ["@babel/preset-env", "@babel/preset-react"]
                    }
                }]
            }
        ]
    }
};
```

In my package.json I have added `sockjs-client` and `stompjs` using the following dependencies and dev dependencies:

```
{
  ...
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "rest": "^2.0.0",
    "sockjs-client": "^1.6.1",
    "stompjs": "^2.3.3"
  },
  ...
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.23.9",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.23.9",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.23.3",
    "babel-loader": "^9.1.3",
    "webpack": "^5.90.3",
    "webpack-cli": "^5.1.4"
  }
}
```

I am not sure how to proceed with resolving these errors. Guidance on resolving these errors would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `require('stompjs');` shouldn't be `const Stomp = require('stompjs');` ??